# 7z installed on ubuntu but 7z command not run with exec() function in php application

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-14.04, unzip, 7zip

How can 7z command run on php application in local system? I am trying to extract 
 zip (7z) file inside php application. Below code run on live server successfully but not on local linux system.
**How can I run 7z unzip command in my php application?**

My existing code is-

```
exec("7z x fileToUnzip.7z -o/opt/lampp/htdocs/"%MyProject/unzipFolder%" -p$pass");
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to provide the full path to the `7z` command. To find out where it is just type `whereis 7z` in your terminal, and use the full path in your exec command:
`exec("/path/to/7z x fileToUnzip.7z -o/opt/lampp/htdocs/"%MyProject/unzipFolder%" -p$pass");`